# Go http cannot handle HTTP requests with no PATH

Tags: http, go

I am writing a small HTTP server that receives HTTP POSTs from some embedded devices. Unfortunately these devices send malformed POST request that contain no PATH component:

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.13.130:8080
Content-Length: 572
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0"?>
....REST OF XML BODY
```

Due to this the Go http never passes the request to any of my handlers and always responds with 400 Bad Request.

Since these are embedded devices and changing the way they send the request is not an option I though maybe I could intercept the HTTP requests and if no PATH is present add one (e.g. /) to it before it passes to the SeverMux.

I tried this by creating my own CameraMux but Go always responds with 400 Bad Request even before calling the ServeHTTP() method from my custom ServeMux (see code below).

Is there a way to modify the Request object at some point before Go http responds Bad Request or there is a way to make Go accept the request even if it has no PATH?

```
package main

import (
  "net/http"                            
  "log"
  "os"
)

type CameraMux struct {                 
  mux *http.ServeMux                    
} 

func (handler *CameraMux) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // Try to fix URL.Path here but the server never reaches this method.    
  log.Printf("URL %v\n", r.URL.Path)
  handler.mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func process(path string) error {
  log.Printf("Processing %v\n", path)
  // Do processing based on path and body  
  return nil
}

func main() {

  http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    path := r.URL.Path[1:]

    log.Printf("Processing path %v\n", path) 

    err := process(path)

    if err != nil {
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest) 
    } else {
      w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
  })

  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &CameraMux{http.DefaultServeMux})

  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
  }

  os.Exit(0)
}
```

Comment: Isn't such request a violation of HTTP spec? No wonder that Go does not support it if it is. According to the [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.2) request URI must be one of four variants, none of which can be empty (see also [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2396#section-3), `abs_path` definition).

Comment: Yes it is a violation but I cannot change the client (embedded camera) to send me correct HTTP POSTS. With ruby/eventmachine I am able to get the POST raw data and fix it before passing it to the handlers. I just wonder if there is a way to do the same in Go.

Comment: Well, it happens) You also could put custom proxy-like server between the client and your program which will fix the request for you (the proxy may operate directly on sockets instead of HTTP requests, so you can also write it in Go). Don't know if it is possible to hook up to Go HTTP internals, so it is possible that proxy will be the only way (except modifying Go library sources, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing occurs within the request parsing logic, which happens before `ServeHTTP` is called.

The HTTP request is read from the socket by the `ReadRequest` function from the `net/http` package.  It will tokenize the first line of the request with an empty URL portion, but then goes on [to parse the URL](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/net/http/request.go#560):

```
if req.URL, err = url.ParseRequestURI(rawurl); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Unfortunately this function will [return an error for an empty URL string](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/net/url/url.go#364), which will in turn aborts the request reading process.

So it doesn't look like there is an easy way to achieve what you're after without modifying the standard library code.

Comment: I copied the whole net/http source to mine and modified this section of the request.go source file. If rawurl is nil or blank I set it to "/" before passing it to url.ParseRequestURI. This is an ugly (and wrong) solution but works for my use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if Go's HTTP parser will allow requests with no URI path element. If it doesn't then you're out of luck. If it does however; you could overwrite the request's path like this:

```
type FixPath struct {}

func (f *FixPath) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.RequestURI = "/dummy/path" // fix URI path
    http.DefaultServeMux.ServeHTTP(w, r) // forward the fixed request to http.DefaultServeMux
}

func main() {

    // register handlers with http.DefaultServeMux through http.Handle or http.HandleFunc, and then...

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &FixPath{})
}
```

Comment: I am out of luck then, this is exactly the same I am doing in my example but the ServeHTTP method is never called. Go returns Bad Request before reaching this point. I think I will have to use a custom Listener and modify the raw data there but this seems error prone.